# How save value to database with foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, foreign-keys

I have problem!
I do not know how save value in database with Foreign key.
I need simple solution!
My foreign key reference on Countries table!

```
public function create(Request $request){

    $brand = new BrandCar();
    $brand->name =  $request->get('brand');
    $brand->country_id = $request->get('country_id'); // This is foreign key 
    $brand->save();
}
```

Comment: Add the code of the form too please

Comment: Does your BrandCar entity has a $country attribut (ManyToOne)?

Comment: What error do you get from this function? Use dd($request->get('country_id')) on your function so we can have more information about the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer guys! I solved this problem. :D

Comment: The problem in the blade template.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your presentation layer (backoffice, otherwise a security issue?) has been setup. But if the country_id is static on a specific view, you could use a hidden form variable:

```
<input type="hidden" name="country_id" value="3">
```